# php write line from a.txt to b.txt if don not exist in b.txt

Tags: php, unique, fwrite

Hi I use this code to copy unique lines from file a.txt to b.txt:

```
<?php
function fileopen($file)
{
$file1 = fopen($file, "r") or ("Unable to open file");
while (!feof($file1))
{
echo fgets($file1);
}
fclose($file1);
}
?>
```

and in body tag i insert:

```
<?php
$lines = file("http://127.0.0.1/a.txt");
$lines = array_unique($lines);
$file = fopen("b.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, implode("\r\n", $lines));
fclose($file);
?>
```

It works great but if you I delete conent in "a.txt" and open .php file again my b.txt file is empty (that's normal). if i change

```
 $file = fopen("b.txt", "a");
```

**to**

```
 $file = fopen("b.txt", "w");
```

every time i refresh .php I get additional line with same data (also normal). I would like to know if there is any SIMPLE solution to use

```
$file = fopen("b.txt", "w");
```

but write data only if it's not already in b.txt file.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @Amal Murali: the title says it all what he wants

Comment: I store data with $_GET['v'] with submit button. Then in console.php I copy a.txt data to b.txt data but only unique files array_unique... but as I wrote if I refresh console.php each time I get unique text from a.txt in b.txt .. and now there are two same lines in b.txt (each refresh new - same line of data). I would like to store, write data in b.txt that's unique in a.txt but not already in b.txt

Comment: @machineaddict: But it looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @machineaddict it's useless to solve a problem when at the root of it there seems to be another problem. All of this will be thrown out if there's a better storing technique that doesn't require unique comparison afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
$file_a = array_unique(file('a.txt'));
$file_b = array_unique(file('b.txt')); // Note : I supposed array_unique here too

$file_b_to_write = fopen('b.txt', 'w');

foreach ($file_a as $line_a) {
     if (!in_array($line_a, $file_b)) {
         fwrite($file_b_to_write, $line_a);
     }
}

fclose($file_b_to_write);
```

Comment: this example gives mi two same lines. 
Content in a.txt:
test

test

test

test

test

Results:
test

test

Two same lines. Also there you are missing one ")" after "if (!in_array($line_a, $file_b)" .. and second time I refresh console.php I get empty page. 3rd refresh gave me results from first time.

Comment: @MatejMerc I don't really get your refresh problem. Just tried the code (with the missing parenthesis) and it's just working fine... You may have a problem due to line breaks, try this : `file('a.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)` and add the line breaks on `frwite : fwrite($file_b_to_write, $line_a) . PHP_EOL;` (or use PHP_EOL before, depends on your current file format)

Answer (score 0):

You could read both files using using the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) command, this way you will get two arrays you could compare, like using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the missing lines from b.txt and add those to the b.txt. With this solution you have to watch out for your memory usage when working with larges files.

Here is an example of my suggested implementation:

```
php > var_dump(file_get_contents('a.txt'));
string(4) "foo
"
php > var_dump(file_get_contents('b.txt'));
string(4) "bar
"
php > $a = file('a.txt');
php > $b = file('b.txt');
php > $missing = array_diff($a, $b);
php > var_dump($missing);
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "foo
"
}
php > file_put_contents('b.txt', $missing, FILE_APPEND);
php > var_dump(file_get_contents('b.txt'));
string(8) "bar
foo
"
```